# Custom PHP Code after successful Joomla Registration

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, registration

I would like to run a small PHP Code after the successful Registration.

Means when anyone register to my Joomla 2.5 website my custom PHP Code should be run after successful Registration.

Anyone kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to build a plugin that is triggered on by the onAfterStoreUser() event.

Also you may want to check this question here: Joomla - [onAfterStoreUser does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255764/joomla-onafterstoreuser-does-nothing)